# How do I use an instance object in Python if it haven't been created yet until the program run?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I finally passed the Honeymoon period in the Python learning Journey. I'm nearly on Month 2 of learning Python and realising that it's going to take a lot longer to have a confidence level that's above 50.

I'm still working on my complex text adventure game. I need help with a feature that I am trying to add. Where the player can message employees that are off of work. The player can request the employee to come back to work, etc. I felt confident and wrote the code for it but what's confusing me and giving me a hard time is the class objects.

As you can see. When the player hires the employee it creates a instance for the new employee.

```
 def hire(self):
                global random_applicant
        
            for x in positions:
                print(x)
            while True:
                choose_position = input(f"Choose a position for {self.first_name}:")
                if choose_position == 'Delivery Driver':
                    print(f"{mPlayer.name}: Okay {self.first_name}, I will be hiring you. You will be a Delivery Driver.")
                    time.sleep(a)
                    self.position = 'Delivery Driver'
                    print(f"{self.first_name}: Thank you so much!! I look forward to working and will not let you down.")
                    time.sleep(a)
                    break
                elif choose_position == 'Cashier':
                    print(
                        f"{mPlayer.name}: Okay {self.first_name}, I will be hiring you. You will be at the cash register.")
                    time.sleep(a)
                    self.position = 'Cashier'
                    print(f"{self.first_name}: Thank you so much!! I look forward to working and will not let you down.")
                    time.sleep(a)
                    break
                elif choose_position == 'Chef':
                    print(f"{mPlayer.name}: Okay {self.first_name}, I will be hiring you. You will be in the back baking")
                    time.sleep(a)
                    self.position = 'Chef'
                    print(f"{self.first_name}: Thank you so much!! I look forward to working and will not let you down.")
                    time.sleep(a)
                    break
                else:
                    print('You entered a wrong key. Try again.')
            mPlayer.employee_count += 1
            if mPlayer.employee_count == 1:
                employee0 = Employees(self.full_name, self.first_name, self.gender, self.previous_job, self.dob,
                                      self.hire_score, self.position, True, 5)
                employee_list.append(employee0)
                employee0.addEmployeeTable()
            elif mPlayer.employee_count == 2:
                employee2 = Employees(self.full_name, self.first_name, self.gender, self.previous_job, self.dob,
                                      self.hire_score, self.position, True, 5)
                employee_list.append(employee2)
                employee2.addEmployeeTable()
            elif mPlayer.employee_count == 3:
                employee3 = Employees(self.full_name, self.first_name, self.gender, self.previous_job, self.dob,
                                      self.hire_score, self.position, True, 5)
                employee_list.append(employee3)
                employee3.addEmployeeTable()
            elif mPlayer.employee_count == 4:
                employee4 = Employees(self.full_name, self.first_name, self.gender, self.previous_job, self.dob,
                                      self.hire_score, self.position, True, 5)
                employee_list.append(employee4)
                employee4.addEmployeeTable()
            elif mPlayer.employee_count == 5:
                employee5 = Employees(self.full_name, self.first_name, self.gender, self.previous_job, self.dob,
                                      self.hire_score, self.position, True, 5)
                employee_list.append(employee5)
                employee5.addEmployeeTable()
            elif mPlayer.employee_count == 6:
                employee6 = Employees(self.full_name, self.first_name, self.gender, self.previous_job, self.dob,
                                      self.hire_score, self.position, True, 5)
                employee_list.append(employee6)
                employee6.addEmployeeTable()
            elif mPlayer.employee_count == 7:
                employee7 = Employees(self.full_name, self.first_name, self.gender, self.previous_job, self.dob,
                                      self.hire_score, self.position, True, 5)
                employee_list.append(employee7)
                employee7.addEmployeeTable()
            elif mPlayer.employee_count == 8:
                employee8 = Employees(self.full_name, self.first_name, self.gender, self.previous_job, self.dob,
                                      self.hire_score, self.position, True, 5)
                employee_list.append(employee8)
                employee8.addEmployeeTable()
            elif mPlayer.employee_count == 9:
                employee9 = Employees(self.full_name, self.first_name, self.gender, self.previous_job, self.dob,
                                      self.hire_score, self.position, True, 5)
                employee_list.append(employee9)
                employee9.addEmployeeTable()
            elif mPlayer.employee_count == 10:
                employee10 = Employees(self.full_name, self.first_name, self.gender, self.previous_job, self.dob,
                                       self.hire_score, self.position, True, 5)
                employee_list.append(employee10)
                employee10.addEmployeeTable()
        
            applicant_list.remove(self)
            print(f"You have now hired {self.first_name}")
            time.sleep(a)
            print("You can view employee information and see their activities in the View Employee section.")
            random_applicant = random.choice(applicant_list)
            manager_menu()
```

So if the player wants to message the employees they can do it in the manager menu function.

```
def manager_menu():
            manager_input = input(f"""
            Balance: ${mPlayer.tip} Level: {mPlayer.level} Position: {mPlayer.position} 
                
            *** You have a new message in your inbox ***
                
            V - View Employee Work Activity
            C - View Employee Schedule 
            T - Conversate with Employees.
            M - Message Employees that are off.
            H - Hire Applicants
            R - Report Employee to Boss Joe
            I - View your inbox {mPlayer.inbox_notifications}
            B - Bake a Pizza
            S - Save Game
            
            
          """)
            if manager_input == 'I' or manager_input == 'i':
                viewinbox()
            elif manager_input == 'H' or manager_input == 'h':
                random_applicant.accept_interview()
            elif manager_input == 'M' or manager_input == 'm':
                pass
```

But I am having a difficult time getting the code to choose the correct employee because the employee objects haven' been created yet until I run the program and hire the employees. I tried using global employee1, employee2 etc. But the employee instances only autofill if I am typing in the **def hire method**. If I try to type the objects in the manager_menu function it doesn't show. When a player types M it will print the prettytable with the hired employees and it will prompt them to enter a employee first or full name to send a message. Once they enter the employee name it will send the player to the sendmessage function.

```
   def sendMessageEmployee(self):
        choose_message = input(f"""
            
            Sending Message to {self.first_name}
            
            A - Ask {self.first_name} to come into work today.
            B - Give {self.first_name} a holiday off.
            C - Ask {self.first_name} about their day.
            D - Thank {self.first_name} for their hard work.
            
            ****** Make a Selection ******
            
            
            """)

        if choose_message == 'A' or choose_message == 'a':
            if mPlayer.ma_duplicate < 1:
                mPlayer.ma_duplicate += 1
                time.sleep(a)
                print(f"You're message was sent to {self.first_name}.")
                message_a_reply_yes = Inbox('RE-Come in for work', random.choice(replied_message_a_phrases_yes),
                                            self.first_name)
                time.sleep(a)
                message_a_reply_yes.message_received_a()
            else:
                print(f"You have already sent this message to {self.first_name}")

        elif choose_message == 'B' or choose_message == 'b':
            if mPlayer.mb_duplicate < 1:
                mPlayer.mb_duplicate += 1
                time.sleep(a)
                print(f"You're message was sent to {self.first_name}.")
                time.sleep(a)
            else:
                print(f"You have already sent this message to {self.first_name}")

        elif choose_message == 'C' or choose_message == 'c':
            if mPlayer.mc_duplicate < 1:
                mPlayer.mc_duplicate += 1
                time.sleep(a)
                print(f"You're message was sent to {self.first_name}.")
                time.sleep(a)
            else:
                print(f"You have already sent this message to {self.first_name}")

        elif choose_message == 'D' or choose_message == 'd':
            if mPlayer.md_duplicate < 1:
                mPlayer.md_duplicate += 1
                time.sleep(a)
                print(f"You're message was sent to {self.first_name}.")
                time.sleep(a)
            else:
                print(f"You have already sent this message to {self.first_name}")
```

I tried creating 10 separate classes for every single employee that gets hired. But that seems more complicated and unnecessary code. So I stuck with having one class for the employees. I tried making the manager_menu a method under the employee class but when calling the manager_method I had to create a fake employee object in order for it to run. But when doing that if I used

```
if choose_recipient == self.first_name or choose_recipient == self.full_name:
       current_recipient = self
       current_recipient.sendMessageEmployee()

else:
     print("Employee not found.")
```

But when I use that code for the manager menu when players press 'M' it will take them to the sendmessage method but the sendmessage method will have the fake employee instance I created as the self name etc. I'm sorry for the long post and thank you so much.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it somewhat difficult to understand the question and what you're trying to do but I'll try my best and feel free to correct me if I'm wrong. I'll start with some design considerations but will omit lots of the code, but hopefully this will help you with the overall game.

But before anything else a word of advice (and please don't take it the wrong way, I've up to recently been a newbie too and I know lots of stuff don't make sense at start): *Without previous programming experience it is too early to start building this sort of programs; you should focus more on tutorials and getting to understand the language and programming.*

First, I'd create a class for the employees. I'll assume employees have a cost to acquire, a name, and a position. Since you want to avoid the player sending duplicate messages add a dictionary for that too.

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, full_name, position, cost):
        self.full_name = full_name
        self.position = position
        self.cost = cost
        self.received_messages = {"a": 0, "b": 0, "c": 0}
```

Then we need a class for the player. You can put anything you think is appropriate in it. I'll just add a few things: a name, a budget, and a method to hire employees, a method to message one of them.

As you said we don't know how many employees (or info about them) when we write the class so we need a mutable data structure. We can use a list (and later iterate over it) or a dictionary (setting the key as the employee's name or ID and the employee object as the value). This is a pretty common occurrence in programming. I prefer the second way for easy lookup by name:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, budget=100):
        self.name = name
        self.budget = budget
        self.employees = {}

    def hire(self, employee):
        self.employees[employee.full_name] = employee
        self.budget -= employee.cost

    def message_employee(self, employee_name, message="a"):
        print(f"Message {message} sent to {employee_name}")

        # Now you can update the employee's messages
        employee = self.employees[employee_name]
        if employee.received_messages[message] == 0:
            employee.received_messages[message] += 1
        else:
            print("You already sent that message to this employee")
```

Now you can create players easily use your code like this to build your game:

```
player = Player("John", 100)

james = Employee("James Jameson", "Cashier", 20)
cindy = Employee("Cindy Johnson", "Delivery Driver", 30)

player.hire(james)
player.hire(cindy)

player.message_employee("James Jameson", "a")

# Now however times we run it, it will tell us we've sent a duplicate 
player.message_employee("James Jameson", "a")
player.message_employee("James Jameson", "a")

# We can send a different message now, or to a different employee
player.message_employee("James Jameson", "b")
player.message_employee("Cindy Johnson", "b")
```

Your manager menu is probably meant to be used as an interface to call other methods of the Player class so I guess it would look something like this:

```
def manager_menu(self):
    action = input("...")
    if action == "h":
        self.hire(...)
```

Good luck, and have fun :)

Comment: Thank you so much it worked :) I understand now. Thank you so much for the information. You are a life saviour.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having trouble following your example or train of thought, but here's some things I might consider in your design.

It looks like you have two entities.  Player and Employee.  I cannot tell how related they are, so they might want a shared parent, but for now, I'd just start with those two classes.

`hire(self)` should be a method off of `Player`. Then instead of a global `mPlayer` you would just use `self`.  And you'd take the input and create a new employee and save it to a list that is part of the Player class.  Alternatively, you can leave `hire()` as part of `Employee` but you should pass in the player object (globals have a bad code smell).  You wouldn't have to create a new Employee instance because you are already working on one that you will have had to create earlier.

In your example, you are taking the input from the user and then assigning them to self, presumably an Employee instance, and then you are creating a new Employee instance.  And you don't need a new variable for each employee.  A list of Employee's will achieve the result you need.

It also seems like `message_menu()` should be a part of Player.  Then you would have access to the list of Employees that you could print for the the user to select the employee to send a message to.

`sendMessageEmployee` can go either way (my preference would be Player), but either way, just pass the other into the function so you have access to both.